# How Authorize Attributes validates a user is valid or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am beginner with authorization in mvc ,I need to know how Authorize Attributes vaild users?
Do i need to do some extra stuff or just need to p ut [Authorize] over actions or controllers

Comment: Perhaps start by reading a tutorial.

Comment: I have seen many articles but i did not get internal working of [Authorize] ,is it mandatory to create user identity for this or it will create automatically?

Comment: If you are using asp.net membership then you can simply start using authorize attribute. If you are using custom authorization then you need to use below code : 

if (Users.AuthenticateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize wont create user automatically. once u have authenticated using forms,oauth etc. Annotating with Aurhorize will call OnAuthorize method and it  checks the corresponding User.Identity.IsAuthenticated value. If true then the action method is invoked.